# What are the item rarity colors in Fortnite?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

While playing *Fortnite Battle Royale*, I’ve seen weapons come in different colors to indicate rarity (white, purple, orange, etc).

What are the item rarity colors in Fortnite? What rank does each color represent?

Comment: It means that its better basically than the previous color like in other games that employ a similar system... are you looking for what exactly is better or just what all the colors are? I'm assuming the better the color, the better the damage.

Comment: @TimmyJim I’m looking for what all the colors are, and what rank each color represents.

Comment: To be fair, the item rarity colors are the same for Save The World as for Battle Royale.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Rarity Levels

**Common** or **White** is the easiest found rarity. The basic form of several weapons (Pistol, Revolver, Assault Rifle, Tactical Shotgun) is found as greys very commonly.

**Uncommon** or **Green** is the second most common. A basic form with usually 1 to 3 more damage is found. However several weapons are green onwards (EG: Pump Shotgun, Hunting Rifle, Tactical SMG) can be found.

**Rare** or **Blue** is the middle tier rarity. Basic forms, not advanced weapons, can be found - every single weapon apart from a Guided Missile, a Semi-Auto Sniper Rifle and a Heavy Shotgun or an advanced gun can be found in blue. Blue weapons have about 5 more damage.

**Epic** or **Purple** is the second best rarity. No Basic forms can be found in Purple - they are upgraded. Semi-Autos and Heavy Shotguns can be found purple onwards.

**Legendary** or **Gold** is the best tier. They are found primarily in Supply Drops - balloons that spawn in shrinking intervals of time, starting at 3:00 min. They do the most damage - usually 6 to 10 more than the grey ones. There are only two Legendary consumables - bush and chug jug.

### Basic and Advanced Forms

The revolver can be found in 4 different rarities. White, Green, Blue, and Purple.

The Hand Cannon, a different weapon, is very similar with a clip of 7 rather than 6. It does more damage and fires slightly faster and accurately with a 9 damage difference.

Comment: @TheApacheKid, I have never once found a grey Tactical Shotgun... why did you add that to the list of grey weapons? Tactical shotguns only appear in colors green-purple. The pump shotgun is the only shotgun you can find as grey.

Comment: @Kyle Rone it was updated today actually

Comment: Yup, this is accurate